# Use imwrite to save processed images to different folder in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I need help with saving processed images to different folder with imwrite.

Currently, I can save all processed images to a single folder.

```
Img_filename=ls('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Guanlin_CNN1D\CNN1D\GF_BSIF\*.jpg');
imageSize = size(Img_filename);
Img_filenum = size(Img_filename,1);
for  img=1:Img_filenum
     img_temp=double((rgb2gray(imread(Img_filename(img,:))))); 
     -----------processing--------
     count = count+1;
     FileName = fullfile('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Guanlin_CNN1D\CNN1D\GF_BSIF\folder_1',sprintf('%03d_circle_cropped.jpg',count));
     imwrite(MM, FileName)
end
```

However, I have 1000 different images in 1 folder and after processing, it will generate 500 images and I want to save the first 500 processed images into folder_1. And the second 500 processed images to folder_2 and the third 500 images to folder_3 and so on...

How to re-write the imwrite function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The root folder I used here is named `Image_Folder` and resides on the desktop. The output folders are named `Folder_1, Folder_2 and Folder_3` and also reside on the desktop. I used two nested loops to control the saving of the images. The outer loop controls which folder to write to and the inner loop controls the writing images 1 through 500. The variable `Image_File_Names` can be used to access the input image file names.

```
%Folder holding the 1000 images%
Image_Path = "/Users/michael/Desktop/Image_Folder";

%Prefix path for output folders%
Export_Path = "/Users/michael/Desktop/Folder_";

%Adding path with input images%
addpath(Image_Path);

%Listing all images in folder directory%
Image_File_Names = ls(Image_Path); 
Image_File_Names = split(Image_File_Names);
Number_Of_Images = length(Image_File_Names) - 1;


for Folder_Index = 1: 3
    
Export_Folder_Path = Export_Path + num2str(Folder_Index) + "/";
mkdir(Export_Folder_Path);
    
  for Image_Index = 1: 500  
    
      %Grab the images as needed%
      Input_Image_Index = 1; %Change this index to another variable to grab images within input folder%
      Image = imread(string(Image_File_Names(Input_Image_Index)));
      
      %***************************************%
      %PROCESS IMAGE%
      %***************************************%
      
      
      
      
      
      %***************************************%
      
      Output_File_Path = Export_Folder_Path + "Image_" + num2str(Image_Index) +".jpg";
      imwrite(Image,Export_Folder_Path+num2str(Image_Index)+".jpg");   
      
    
  end
end
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**